# Replacing current POE adapter for router with a UPS POE adapter

Tags: router, power-over-ethernet

My Internet Service provider has set me up with a router / modem that is outdoors enclosed in a plastic en-closer.  It's currently powered with POE adapter [POE-24-7W-G-WH](https://dl.ubnt.com/datasheets/poe/PoE_Adapters_DS.pdf).  The POE adapter is in my basement.

What I want is to replace that POE adapter with a UPS POE adapter, so that during power outages my internet is not interrupted.  So I purchased a [mini UPS with POE output](https://www.amazon.ca/Battery-Backup-10400mAh-Output-Uninterruptible/dp/B0CG2QT68N/ref=sr_1_15?crid=3OHCHELHJ2ZMC&keywords=poe%20upc&qid=1693845324&sprefix=poe%20upc%2Caps%2C611&sr=8-15).

However when I switch from the [POE-24-7W-G-WH](https://dl.ubnt.com/datasheets/poe/PoE_Adapters_DS.pdf) to the [mini UPS](https://www.amazon.ca/Battery-Backup-10400mAh-Output-Uninterruptible/dp/B0CG2QT68N/ref=sr_1_15?crid=3OHCHELHJ2ZMC&keywords=poe%20upc&qid=1693845324&sprefix=poe%20upc%2Caps%2C611&sr=8-15), my switch is no longer recognizing any activity from the outdoor router (its as though the outdoor router is not powered).  I have a POE Checker (NF-488) and I tested the power coming from both POE devices and both report roughly the same:

- Both indicate powered pins: 4,5,7,8
- POE-24-7W-G-WH reports +24.1 VDC
- The Mini UPS reports +23.7 VDC
- Both report 0.7 watts

Any suggestions as to what I might be missing?  Or what to try to troubleshoot?

Here's a diagram of my setup:
[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpmbU.jpg)

Comment: We need to know what is this outdoor router/modem.

Comment: I spoke with my Internet Provider and they called the outdoor device a "Fiber Modem". Although I suspect what they mean by that is an ONT? They are telling me they don't have the model of the unit documented anywhere.  I included in my post a diagram of my setup

Comment: Are you using the same cable for both? What's its length?

Comment: Does the modem/ONT have any LEDs to indicate whether it _is_ powered or not? Does either the old PoE supply, or the new UPS, or the ONT, have 802.3af(/at) mentioned on the labels or manuals?

Comment: Im taking the same ethernet cables from the POE-24-7W-G-WH device and switching them to the Mini UPS one.  The powered ethernet cable that runs outside is 20-30 ft.  The one going to the switch is no more than 6ft.  Also my POE checker is reporting both devices as Non Standard POE device.  Based on reference below, they are both passive (so 802.3af/at/bt wouldn't apply).  Thanks all for the input, I might just buy a AC UPS for the POE-24-7W-G-WH or try another POE mini UPS.

https://community.fs.com/blog/active-vs-passive-poe-switch.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why my Mini UPS' POE output was not able to power my service provider's "Fiber Modem", but found another way to power it using a [POE Injector device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x67UU.jpg)

I'm now powering the POE Injector device using 24V DC output from my Mini UPS and I now have internet during power outages.